# Button shape not changed in style

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the button shape with round edges but somehow it does not work when I define it in my styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="ButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FFFF</item>
        <item name="android:shape">rectangle</item>
        <item name="android:bottomRightRadius">7dp</item>
        <item name="android:bottomLeftRadius">7dp</item>
        <item name="android:topRightRadius">7dp</item>
        <item name="android:topLeftRadius">7dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

main.xml button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="@string/sSettings" />
```

Only the Font Color is changed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this :http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/customize-button-in-android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare a background drawable for the button. 
Do this in res/drawables. Make a new drawable file like this:

/res/drawable/button_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="7dp" />
    <solid android:color="#666666"/>

</shape>
```

then in your layout do:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="@string/sSettings" />
```

if you want to set each corner you can also do this with:

```
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
```

Have a [look here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) for all the options.

Answer (score 1):

Define the shape as a drawable `rounded_corners.xml` and in styles just set it as the background for the button.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#00FFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

and in styles:

```
<style name="Button">            
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corners</item>       
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

i've done it with this:

```
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" 
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
```